# Listview get item text

Tags: android, listviewitem

I need to grab selected item TEXT (not id).
What can I write under onListItemClick to do that?
I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIObjectValue cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.IJavaArray
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDetailFormattersManager.getCompiledExpression(JavaDetailFormattersManager.java:396)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDetailFormattersManager.resolveFormatter(JavaDetailFormattersManager.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDetailFormattersManager.access$1(JavaDetailFormattersManager.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.JavaDetailFormattersManager$3.run(JavaDetailFormattersManager.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$ThreadJob.run(JDIThread.java:2751)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the things passed to `onItemClick` is the view that was clicked:

> abstract void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)

Cast `view` to the appropriate type and call `getText()` on it; for example:

```
final String text = ((TextView)view).getText();
```

Comment: I am using EfficientAdapter and this method does not work. ANy idea why?

Comment: I did: String item=(String) ((TextView) v).getText(); and crashes with  ClassCastException

Comment: One more thing - because it is EfficientAdapter ((TextView)view) cannot work, because the view is really the LinearLayout

Comment: Don't forget to add toString() to the end of getText()

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this and it also depends on whether you are getting text from simple listView or from Custom ListView(with custom_list_item.xml).

**For Simple ListView**

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        String text = lv.get(position).tostring().trim();//first method 
        final String text = ((TextView)view).getText();// second method
}});
```

**For Custom ListView**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
//where list_content is the id of TextView in listview_item.xml

}});
```