# How to get the value from the listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

How to get the value from  the `ListView` ,

i.e when an list item is clicked it sends the data from the `ListView`and set the value of `ListView` in an `EditText`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(<Your Class Name>.this,
                "posisiton: "+position+" "+"Id: "+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {  
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {  
            String str = ((TextView)childView).getText().toString();
            (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01).setText(str);
        }

      });
```

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513538/listview-get-item-text) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513538/listview-get-item-text) should help

Answer (score 0):

```
View curr = adapter.getView(getSelectedItemPosition(),null,null);
TextView c = (TextView)curr.findViewById(R.id.detail);
```