# dynamic listview buttons problem intent in android

Tags: android, listview, button, dynamic

I have  query in dynamic listview buttons. I have 2 buttons in my dynamic listview. I can see the onclick event and toast appears. But when I try to pass a intent to next activity it is not working. Kindly tell me where I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
ViewHolder holder; 

   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptor_content, null);
      // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
      // views
      // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLine);
      //    holder.iconLine = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconLine);
            holder.buttonLine = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonLine);
            holder.DbuttonLine = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DbuttonLine);
            holder.textLine2 =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLine2);
            holder.mobile =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mobile);
            holder.newmes =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newmessage);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        private int pos = position;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                 }
      });
        holder.buttonLine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        private int pos = position;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //Toast.makeText(context, "Delete-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), messsagelist.class);
            //startActivity(myIntent);

            this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


            }
        private void startActivityForResult(Intent myIntent, int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
      });
      holder.DbuttonLine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      private int pos = position;
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(context, "Details-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });
      convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `getContext()` code to use your activity context.

Replace:

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), messsagelist.class);
        //startActivity(myIntent);

        this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

With:

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(yourActivityName.this, messsagelist.class);
        //startActivity(myIntent);

        this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

Edit: Fixed typo in code.

Comment: or `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Intent myIntent = new Intent(yourActivityName.this, messsagelist.class);
        //startActivity(myIntent);
 This gives me error:Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token ",", delete this token
 - The constructor Intent(Class<messsagelist>) is 
  undefined and Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity
        this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);..Pls suggest me i am working on same for past 3 days.. My query is i need to intent to next activity when i click on dynamic buttons in listview.

Comment: `yourActivityName.this` should be the name of your activity. I didn't literally mean 'yourActivityName'. If you're still struggling, post your entire activity code and I will take a look again, make sure you had a reply to this comment so I can check back.

Comment: my code seems to be big. How can i send you my code. Pls reply me sir.

Comment: sir i am sending you a link USing this link you can download and save the file. " http://www.yousendit.com/download/M0RyZGVZYXlPSHhFQlE9PQ "

Comment: I got the result.. Thanks a lot..                               Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, newactivityname.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: I have 1 more query to be solved. when i click the button i am able to intent to corresponding activity. Now I ve few contacts in my listview. Each item has a button that starts an other activity. My query is how can i pass the value dynamically to next screen and place that value in edittext in that screen. Eg. I need to copy the phone no from 1 screen to next screen and place that phone no in edittext in next screen. Kindly help me in this issue sir.

Comment: You need to return the value like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966055/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-listview and pass it using intent data, which you can then get on the next activity, see: http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-intents-to-pass-data-and-return-results-between-activities/